# c++: Making a histogram with arrays, pointers, for loops. I'm right there, I'm probably thinking too hard

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, for-loop, histogram

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int* histogram (int arr[], int size);
double deviation (int arr[], int size);
double mean (int arr[], int size);

int main ()  {
   int scores[100];
   int count = 0;
   int temp;
   double sd;

cout << "***===***===Lab 5 - Stats===***===***\n";
cout << "Welcome to the Historgam Generator and Stardard Deviation Caluclator!" << endl;
cout << "Enter some scores, 0 to 109, limit 100, enter -1 to quit." << endl;

while (count < 109) {//puts limit on array
    cout << "Enter value " << count + 1 << ":   ";
    cin >> temp; //initialize data
    if (temp == -1) {
        break;//end program
    }
    else if (temp < 0) {
        cout << "An invalid score has been entered." << endl;
        break;//end program
    }
    else {
        scores[count] = temp;
        count++;//valid number, continue counting when entered corretly
    }
}

//help from here
//histogram (scores, count);
int* bin = histogram (scores, count);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    int displayNo = 0;
    //bin[scores[count]]++;
    //count is the number of numbers entered.
    //scores[] is the array of scores entered by user
    //bin[9] is the address of the element in the array

    cout << displayNo << "| ";
    for (int k = 0; k < scores[i]; k++) {
        cout << '*';
    }
        cout << endl;
}

//to here

sd = deviation (scores, count);
cout << "SD: " << sd << endl;

//hold window open
system ("pause");
return 0;
}

int* histogram (int scores[], int size) {
    int* bin = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (scores[i] >= 90) {
            bin[9]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 80 && scores[i] < 90) {
            bin[8]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 70 && scores[i] < 80) {
        bin[7]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 60 && scores[i] < 70) {
        bin[6]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 50 && scores[i] < 60) {
        bin[5]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 40 && scores[i] < 50) {
        bin[4]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 30 && scores[i] < 40) {
        bin[3]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 20 && scores[i] < 30) {
        bin[2]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 10 && scores[i] < 20) {
        bin[1]++;
    }
    else if (scores[i] >= 0 && scores[i] < 10) {
        bin[0]++;
    }
}
return bin;
}

//calculates standard deviation
double deviation (int scores[], int size) {
double avg = 0;
double sd = 0;
avg = mean (scores, size);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    sd += pow ((scores[i] - avg), 2);
}

sd = sqrt (sd / size);
return sd;
}

//calculates the mean/average
double mean (int scores[], int size) {
    double sum = 0;
    double mean = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    sum += scores[i];
}
mean = sum / size;
return mean;
}
```

And all I have to do is get the histogram in my program to show like this:

9| ***

8| **

7| *

6| ***

5| **********************

4| *******************

3| ****

2|

1|

0|

SD: 15.2579

---

That's if I entered the numbers from this test case:

Case 2: 30, 40, 45, 102, 35, 42, 65, 89, 55, 48, 56, 46, 42, 54, 56, 51, 47, 50, 51, 50, 50, 47, 52, 53, 47, 44, 69, 35, 40, 45, 35, 42, 65, 55, 48, 100, 56, 46, 42, 54, 56, 51, 47, 50, 51, 50, 50, 47, 52, 53, 47, 78, 80, and 95

I have the SD part down, but I just don't get what logic to use with the for loops to make it look like this. Could I get some help with the part maked above?

****UPDATE****
Here are the directions given to me by my instructor:

Program Requirements

Name your program file stats.cpp
Do not use any global variables
Use only iostream and iomanip functions for I/O and formatting (no stdio)
Read a list of integers from the console one at a time
Place each integer into an array
Allow for a maximum (not total) of 100 scores (see Arrays and Loops (Links to an external site.)Links to an external site. - the examples at the bottom of the page)
None of the entered scores will be < 0
Count how many integers are entered
Stop the data entry and begin the calculations when the user enters a -1 (do not include the -1 in the data)
Recall that I use a test bed to help score your labs, which means that it will be a simple program that provides input to your program - the test bed will fail if your program deviates from the above requirements.
Group the scores in the histogram as follows:

```
Bin 9: score ≥ 90
Bin 8: score ≥ 80 but < 90
Bin 7: score ≥ 70 but < 80
    .
    .
    .
Bin 1: score ≥ 10 but < 20
Bin 0: score < 10
```

Note that the scores include some that have earned extra credit; your program must work for scores up to 109. I used an array of integers called bin and filled the array in the histogram function: int bins[10]; Each element in the bins array is a counter that counts how many scores were in a specific range. Printing the histogram is similar to printing the pyramid of Xs or drawing the pine tree: use two for loops, one nested inside the other. The outer loop walks through the bins array and the inner loop prints each '*' on a given line.

Whenever you use a variable as an accumulator or counter (i.e., you use it something like this: sum += ... or count++) it must be initialized to 0. Neither automatic nor dynamic variables are automatically initialized, so programmers must remember to do that as a part of the program. An array is just a list of variables accessed with one name, which implies that when an array is used as a set of accumulators or counters that every element of an array must be initialized to 0. Please see Figure 2 (Links to an external site.)Links to an external site..

Your program will have four functions (the statistical functions must follow main):

Add function prototypes for the three statistical functions at the top of the program
main
Define your array here
Read the data here
Call histogram
Print the histogram (see the "Test Cases" below for an example of the required output)
Call deviation
Print the standard deviation (steps v and vi may be combined if desired)
histogram (pass in whatever arguments you need)
Calculate the histogram
Return the histogram array, either as the function return value (using the "return" keyword) or through the argument list. Choose one of the three techniques illustrated in Arrays And Functions (Links to an external site.)Links to an external site..
deviation (pass in whatever arguments you need, return a double)
Call mean (i.e., average of all scores)
Calculate the standard deviation
Return the standard deviation
mean (pass in whatever arguments you need, return a double) - see average.cpp (Links to an external site.)Links to an external site.
Extra Credit
If you get done with the assignment early, you may challenge yourself by try either or both of the following extra credit assignments:

(5 points) Print the histogram using only a single loop. See one of my posted solutions for lab 3 for a hint.
(5 points) Complete Requirement 5 (making the histogram) using only computation
You may use only one (1) loop
Your single loop may contain only one statement (no cheating by using the comma operator)
You may NOT use an if, switch, or conditional statement
You may NOT use a function call
You may not move any of the logic into the print function
You may use multiple loops to print the histogram (unless you are doing extra credit 1) but not to fill the array
Alternatively, for 5 points extra credit, complete Requirement 5 as above but you may use a conditional statement.

Comment: Example: `for` loop: `for ( int i = count; i >= 0; --i ) { ... }` and `int displayNo = 9;` ... `cout << displayNo-- << "| ";` and I believe you can figure the rest easily.

Comment: This `displayNo` is just a counter to show like `count`, right? If so, you can directly use `count` instead of this extra variable.

Comment: I do have to get each number in "bins" of 10. So, 9 is 90+, 8 is 80 to 89, etc.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Do not allow more than 100 values entered, writing to `scores[100]` would be an access out of bounds for an arrayof size 100. I.e. the `109` in the code is questionable.

Comment: What is the output you get and what is not satisfying about it? I.e. where is your precise problem?

Comment: `int displayNo = 0;` then `cout << displayNo << "| ";` and no changing of `displayNo` anywhere will probably give you a lot of "0|". You probably want `cout << i << "| ";`

Comment: The part you're asking for help on is just printing out the histogram? Just iterate over the bins and for each one print as many stars as the size of the bin.

Comment: @Rotem could you be more specific on how I would do that? That sounds exactly like What I need

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < numBins; i++) { for (int k = 0; k < bins[i]; k++) cout << '*'; count << endl; }`

Comment: you can also use `std::string{ bins[i], '*' }` to repeat "*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to get what you wanna do, but is that it ?

```
void histogram(int scores[], int size, int *bin)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       int binId = scores[i] / 10;
       if (binId > 9) binId = 9;
       bin[binId]++; 
   }
}

// called from main:
int bin[10]; // declared here as global var, so it is well destroyed
histogram(scores, size, bin); // pass bin pointer, avoid returning pointer with assigned memory from within a fonction, this will trap you.
```

If the bin always have the same "sorting criteria", x / 10 will actually floor the value so you don't need to have all those comparisons.

---

For display something like this ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    cout << i << "| ";
    for (int k = 0; k < bin[i]; k++) 
    {
        cout << '*';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

if you are lost in loops, it can actually get tricky to have loops into loops. Some codes have like 3-4 levels of loops and becomes a nightmare. Refactoring to sub-function will make your code more readable and easier to debug.

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
{
    cout << i << "| ";
    print_stars(bin[i])
    cout << endl;
}

void print_stars(int amount)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < amount; k++) 
    {
        cout << '*';
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great! There's just a problem with your function call in the first part of code. I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Can you indicate where ? The *bin* variable is defined outside of the function and then passed as a pointer, this is to avoid global variable as specified on the requirements.

Comment: histogram(scores, size, &bin);

Comment: size is saying that "no instance of overloaded function "size" matches the required type.

Comment: You've helped so much! I just want to get it to work

Comment: You probably have another function or variable with the same name *size*. Try to rename it

Comment: should it be count instead?

Comment: Based on your code, it should be called with count: histogram(scores, count, bin); indeed

Comment: now, the only thing it's not doing is displaying the stars. I used the nested for loops try to do it.

Comment: without seeing your code it's difficult to tell. Probably something about the scope of the bin variable.

Comment: `  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
  cout << i << "| ";
  for (int k = 0; k < bin[i]; k++)//bin
  {
   cout << '*';
  }
  cout << endl;
 }`

Comment: void histogram (int scores[], int count, int* bin) {
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  int binId = scores[i] / 10;
  if (binId > 9) binId = 9;
  bin[binId]++;
 }
}

Comment: From that point you should be able to have it running with some effort, the comment section is not really for code debugging. Just check the scope of the variable and that bin is really accessible and not destroyed. means declared at the right place.

Answer (score -1):

After having to do this assignment myself I have figured out a way. This might not be helpful for you at this time, but for anyone new it can be. Instead of trying to return a dynamic array I returned it through argument/parameter.

Histogram prototype

```
int* histogram(int arr[], int size, int* bin);
```

The Histogram function

```
int* histogram (int arr[], int size, int* bin) {

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (scores[i] >= 90) {
            bin[9]++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] >= 80 && scores[i] < 90) {
            bin[8]++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] >= 70 && scores[i] < 80) {
            bin[7]++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] >= 60 && scores[i] < 70) {
            bin[6]++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] >= 50 && scores[i] < 60) {
            bin[5]++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] >= 40 && scores[i] < 50) {
            bin[4]++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] >= 30 && scores[i] < 40) {
            bin[3]++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] >= 20 && scores[i] < 30) {
            bin[2]++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] >= 10 && scores[i] < 20) {
            bin[1]++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] >= 0 && scores[i] < 10) {
            bin[0]++;
        }
    }

    return bin;
}
```

Calling the function and printing the histogram in the main function

```
int bin[10];
histogram(scores, count, bin); 

for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
    cout << i << "| ";
    for (int j = 0; j < bin[i]; j++)
    {
        cout << '*';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```